# Easy DAWG creation algorithm?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, graph

I need to create a DAWG (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph) structure for my Scrabble player given the word list in a file. I'm using Java. I need to do it only once and then store it in a file or files. I've seen so far 2 approaches: 1) build a Trie and reduce it to a DAWG or 2) build a DAWG right away. Since I need to do it only once I guess I just want the easiest algorithm to implement that does it. Speed and memory requirements don't matter.

Also I want to know how I should store the structure in memory at runtime and how I should save it in a file? The DAWG is basically a graph which suggests using some nodes and edges/pointers of some very simple classes written by me but I saw implementations using array and offsets (in this array) which seems complicated and illegible. This time I care both about memory size (at runtime and of the saved file) and speed of loading the DAWG/using the DAWG.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest and most efficient DAWG construction algorithm  is defined in [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.37.7600), and requires the set of words the DAWG is to represent to be sorted. Given that you plan on constructing a DAWG from a pre-existing word list, that list may already be sorted, or can be for this purpose.

I've cursorily transcribed the pseudocode of the algorithm in a more "programmer-friendly" format than that in which it is given in the paper (disclaimer: I may have made some transcription errors; you should probably take a look at the original to determine if there are any) :

```
Given:
        startState is the state from which traversal of the DAWG is to start
        register is a map of representations (hint: hashes) OF graphs which extend 
        from states in the DAWG TO said states

While there is newWord in wordList
    Get newWord from wordList
    Determine longestPrefix of newWord, starting from startState, which already exists in DAWG
    Get longestPrefixEndState, the state which the sequence of transitions defined by longestPrefix leads to
    Get suffix of newWord, the substring of newWord after longestPrefix
    if longestPrefixEndState has children 
        replace_or_register(longestPrefixEndState)
    endIf
    Create the sequence of transitions and states defined by suffix, starting from longestPrefixEndState
endWhile
replace_or_register(startState)


function replace_or_register(argState)
    Get greatestCharEndState of argState, the state which the lexicographically-greatest-char-labelled-transition in the outgoing transition set of argState leads to
    if greatestCharEndState has children
        replace_or_register(greatestCharEndState)
    endIf
    if there exists state in DAWG that is in the register and is equivalent (has an identical graph extending from it) to greatestCharEndState
        Redefine the transition that extends from argState to greatestCharEndState, as one that extends from argState to state
        Delete greatestCharEndState
    endIf
    else 
        add greatestCharEndState to the register
    endElse
```

Given that you are using Java, you can take advantage of the [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface to handle all of your serialization & deserialization needs.

If you're interested in an existing DAWG implementation in Java which implements the algorithm above, check out [MDAG](https://github.com/klawson88/MDAG), which also provides several nifty features which other implementations do not (including adding and removing strings on-the-fly), and is maintained by me!

Answer (score 0):

I had to implement such a structure in C for one of my client once. The final structure is loaded from an xml file describing the character set and the dawg, another process created the xml file from a word list.

### step 1 : structure to build the first dawg serialized to an xml file

We used :

```
typedef struct _s_build_node build_node_t;
struct _s_build_node {
  char_t letter;
  build_node_t* first_child;
  build_node_t* right_sibling;

  hash_t hash;
  size_t depth;
  size_t ID;
};
typedef struct _s_build_dawg {
  charset_t charset;
  node_t* all_nodes; // an array of all the created nodes
  node_t* root;
} build_dawg_t;
```

siblibgs are ordered ascending, end-of-word special character is less than any other character.
The algorithm is quite simple :

```
// create the build dawg
foreach word in wordlist
  insert(dawg, word)
// compact the dawg
compact(dawg)
// generate the xml file
xml_dump(dawg)
```

In order to compact the dawg, we computed a hash value for each node. Two nodes with the same hash can be *factorized*. This part can be tricky. Only the node with the lowest depth is kept, the others are deleted and their parents now point to the one kept.
Once compacted we assign a unique ID to each node (via bfs, ID are between 0 and N-1, N is the number of nodes in the compacted dawg). The xml file simply described the trie :

```
<dawg>
  <charset ....>
    ...
  </charset>

  <node ID="node_id" letter="letter" fist_child="first_child_ID" next_sibling="next_sibling_id" />
  <node .... />
  <node .... />
  <node .... />
</dawg>
```

### step 2 : The final dagw

The structure is a little bit simpler

```
typedef struct {
  char_t letter;
  size_t first_child;
  size_t next_sibling;
} node_t;

typedef struct {
  node_t nodes[];
  ... whatever you need ...
} dawg_t;
```

Here root is dawg.nodes[0], and first_child/next_sibling is an index in the nodes array. Creating such a struct is easy from the xml file. The main drawback is that any wordlist modification triggers the generation of a new xml file.