# Saving a DAWG in java

Tags: java, android, algorithm, serialization, dawg

I'm looking to create a DAWG structure to validate words entered by a user. This is going to be used in an Android App. Would my best option be to serialize a DAWG structure outside the app then load it upon the start? Or is there a better way to work with a DAWG?

Comment: Dawg, I don't know.  As long as you only serialize once (the less you do per app load, the better), then loading should be quicker.  You'll need to ask user for permission of course.  Maybe this will help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331755/easy-dawg-creation-algorithm

Comment: @MohammadS. Why would you need to ask the user for permission?

Comment: @kabuko:  I may be wrong, but don't you need to ask permission from the user to do anything outside the app's scope?  Such as accessing the internet.

Comment: @MohammadS. I suspect you're misunderstanding the wording here. Serializing "outside the app" as I understand it would mean serializing the DAWG with another application--mostly likely on a desktop--then putting that serialized file into the Android app, perhaps as an asset. No extra permissions are necessary.

Comment: Ahh, I see.  It was definitely a misunderstanding then.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a small amount of data, you could definitely load up a pre-serialized graph at start, but you'll have to be careful about memory consumption. It'll be pretty easy to exhaust a low-end device's memory quickly if you have a large dictionary. It may be better to take the more memory-efficient approach and keep the graph on disk and only load individual nodes into memory as needed. This will require you to think out how you're serializing the graph.